# eBay API GetSellerListCall Is Not Returning Items On .NET SDK

Tags: .net, ebay-api

When asking for the seller listings, the returned list is empty and no error occurs.

The code is:

```
oGetSellerListCall.UserID = sellerUsername;
TimeFilter tf = new TimeFilter();
tf.TimeFrom = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
tf.TimeTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
oGetSellerListCall.EndTimeFilter = tf;
oGetSellerListCall.Execute();
```

Note that this code was working some time ago.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You've provided a Filter in the future, so there will be no results

```
tf.TimeFrom = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
tf.TimeTo = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thank you, but still not working. I believe the API is returning my own item instead of the items from the seller specified at "oGetSellerListCall.UserID".